# How to copy an Excel Template to another sheet in same Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am new to OpenXML. My concepts are not clear completely.
I am using following code -

```
Package package = Package.Open(newFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            excelDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(package);
            WorkbookPart wbPart = excelDoc.WorkbookPart;
            Sheet templateSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where((s) => s.Name == "Sheet1").FirstOrDefault();
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)(obj.Count / 4); i++)
            {
                WorkbookPart workBookpart = excelDoc.WorkbookPart;
                Workbook workbook = workBookpart.Workbook;
                Sheets sheets = workbook.Sheets;
                WorksheetPart workSheetPart = excelDoc.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>("workSheet" + (i+2));
                Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();
                SheetData sheetdata = new SheetData();
                worksheet.Append(sheetdata);
                workSheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;
                sheets.Append(templateSheet.CloneNode(true));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)(obj.Count / 4); i++)
            {
                uint sheetId = 1;
                if (excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    sheetId = excelDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                }
                Sheet temp = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Skip(i + 1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
                temp.Name = "Sheet" + (i + 2);
                temp.Id = "workSheet" + (i + 2);
                temp.SheetId = sheetId;
            }
```

this code is creating sheets but template is not there which is present at "Sheet1". How should I do this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you have right now your issue is that you're copying the `Sheet`, which gives you the metadata of your template sheet, but doesn't copy any of the associated `WorksheetPart` objects which contain the actual contents of the sheet.  To do that you need part of what's in [this MSDN Blogs post by Brian Jones](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/02/19/how-to-copy-a-worksheet-within-a-workbook.aspx), specifically the part where he copies the sheet and all it's parts to the new workbook.  I can provide examples of how I'd do this if necessary.